# Navigation hierarchy on Android?

Tags: android, ios, navigation

I've recently been looking into the navigation system that Android uses with as intention to port my iOS app that uses an `UITabBarController` containing multiple `UINavigationController`s. To replace the tab bar (which is not available on Android) I settled on using the built in `DrawerLayout`.

From what I've read, navigation in Android is generally done by creating an `Intent`, providing it with extras and then just replacing the current activity. This automatically makes sure the back button works, and optionally the back button in the top left if enabled.

However, I am not sure how to implement this way of navigation with [the navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). The tutorial tells me to create a `DrawerLayout` containing a `FrameLayout` and a `ListLayout` where the `FrameLayout` will contain the actual application and the `ListLayout` will contain the navigation. This would mean that when I use the method described above to "navigate", it would replace the activity and thus removing the drawer.

What would be the best way to implement what I want (basic navigation with back button support while maintaining a global drawer navigation menu)? The possible options I can come up with is always keeping the same activity and dynamically replacing the `FrameLayout`, but that would mean a lot of boilerplate to render and possibly a hack to support the back button (and there would be no animations :(). The other option would be to just render the drawer on every activity (via subclassing or something), but that would mean that if the user navigates a lot the back button "stack" would become quite large.

I have tried to explain what I need in as much detail as possible, but it is quite hard to explain the concept. Basically, I want something similar to the `UINavigationController`s in the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: I'd suggest using android studio template for app with navigation drawer, you can use fragments as main component to show content. Back button behaviour is customisable, you don't have to commit every fragment transaction to backstack.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have one Activity with one `NavigationDrawer` and present the user with different views by switching `Fragments` back and forth within that one Activity. You would use the `FragmentManager` to switch between different `Fragments`.
Or you can use multiple `Activities` that all have a `NavigationDrawer`.

Second option might sound more difficult but it really isn't. You create a base `Activity` that all your Activities inherit from and all let them have their own `NavigationDrawer`, no problem.

Sure there's something in between or something completely different, but that's the most straightforward approaches I can think of.

The tutorial you've probably used (the one with the planets) is imho a bit misleading because it assumes a very basic app structure. If you have only little different 'screens' that might work, for a very complex application it's not suitable (again, in my opinion).

I've always opted for the second option because handling the navigation / backstack is just easier with Activities / `Intents`. 
There's [loads of different flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) that you can set to your `Intent` to influence their navigation behaviour.

Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) and [that](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) documentation. These documents might have been written when the `NavigationDrawer` pattern was not all that common but they are still useful.